# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.UrlSet.includeClassesUrl

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I am getting following exceptions while deploying  i am using tomcat 7. I am using netbeans7.4  for development.
I have included `struts2.3.15` jar files and hibernet jar files.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.UrlSet.includeClassesUrl(Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/ClassLoaderInterface;Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/UrlSet$FileProtocolNormalizer;)Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/util/finder/UrlSet;
        at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildUrlSet(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:442)
        at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.readUrls(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:389)
        at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
        at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:215)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4746)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5399)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: try to stop your web server and then run it again

Comment: Seems like you have a mess of library versions. Post the content of `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @manish Sahu if my answer is helpful you can select my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

Error is Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.

Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

Try to [download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxworkcore221jar.htm) latest version of jar file

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError:` is generally thrown when there is conflict for the methods in included jars or may be due to different version of included dependent jars. Try removing unnecessary jars and if still issue is not resolved check the version of included jars